# OpenGL 3+, как в моем коде сделать простейшую анимацию перемещение фигуры в сторону? допустим прибавляя значения в главном цикле!

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

OpenGL 3+, как в моем коде сделать простейшую анимацию перемещение фигуры в сторону? допустим прибавляя значения в главном цикле! я так делал в старом OpenGL!а сейчас фигура вообще не двигается... не чего не происходит...

```
#include <iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

const GLint WIDTH = 800, HEIGTH = 600;

const GLchar *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
"}";



const GLchar *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 color;\n"
"void main () \n"
"{\n"
"color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
"}";



int main () {

    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow (WIDTH, HEIGTH, "Learn OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;

    glfwGetFramebufferSize (window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight);
    if (nullptr == window) {
        cout<<"Failed to create GLFW window"<<endl;
        glfwTerminate ();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (GLEW_OK != glewInit()) {
        cout<<"Failed to initialize GLEW"<<endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glViewport (0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader (GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    glShaderSource (vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL );
    glCompileShader (vertexShader);

    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];

    glGetShaderiv (vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog (vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        cout<<"ERROR::SHADER::COMPILATION_FAILED"<<infoLog<<endl;
    }

    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource (fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader (fragmentShader);

    glGetShaderiv (fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog (fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        cout<<"ERROR::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED"<<infoLog<<endl;
    }
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram ();

    glAttachShader (shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader (shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram (shaderProgram);

    glGetProgramiv (shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog (shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        cout<<"ERROR::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED"<<infoLog<<endl;
    }

    glDeleteShader (vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader (fragmentShader);

    GLfloat vertices [] {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f
    };
    GLuint VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays (1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers (1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray (VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer (0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof (GLfloat), (GLvoid *) 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);

    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindVertexArray (0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        glfwPollEvents();

        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        vertices [0] += 0.1;
        vertices [3] += 0.1;
        vertices [6] += 0.1;

        glUseProgram ( shaderProgram );
        glBindVertexArray ( VAO );
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glBindVertexArray (0);

        glfwSwapBuffers (window);
    }
    glDeleteVertexArrays (1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers (1, &VBO);
    glfwTerminate ();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас две ошибки первая это шейдер, вторая это отрисовка шейдера.

Первая проблема в том что в шейдере не прописана переменная(вектор) отвечающая за смещение.

вот шейдер из проекта где "движение" есть.

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;

uniform vec2 posOffset;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(pos.x + posOffset.x, pos.y + posOffset.y, pos.z, 1.0);
}
```

Как видите в отличие в нём есть вектор `posOffset` отвечающий за смещение по X и Y.

Вторая ошибка шейдер стоит писать не строкой(*с ним сложнее работать когда он виде строки*), а в виде файла `.vert`. Также заметил  что в вашем коде шейдер статичен, ибо даже такой код не приводит к 'движению' треугола :3

```
const GLchar *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"gl_Position = vec4(position.x + 0.01, position.y + 0.01,  position.z, 1.0);\n"
"}";
```

По сему предлагаю посмотреть тот вариант кода который я предоставил.

---

Вот проект в котором реализовано движение прямоугольника, а также изменение его цвета (без заголовочного .pro файла):

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "GL/glew.h"    // Important - this header must come before glfw3 header
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include "glm/glm.hpp"

#include "ShaderProgram.h"

// Global Variables
const char* APP_TITLE = "Introduction to Modern OpenGL - Shaders";
const int gWindowWidth = 800;
const int gWindowHeight = 600;
GLFWwindow* gWindow = NULL;
bool gWireframe = false;

// Function prototypes
void glfw_onKey(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);
void glfw_onFramebufferSize(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void showFPS(GLFWwindow* window);
bool initOpenGL();

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Main Application Entry Point
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    if (!initOpenGL())
    {
        // An error occured
        std::cerr << "GLFW initialization failed" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Set up our quad

    // 1. Set up an array of vertices for a quad (2 triangls) with an index buffer data
    //   (What is a vertex?)
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,     // Top left
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,     // Top right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,     // Bottom right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f      // Bottom left
    };

    GLuint indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2,  // First Triangle
        0, 2, 3   // Second Triangle
    };

    // 2. Set up buffers on the GPU
    GLuint vbo, ibo, vao;

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);                  // Generate an empty vertex buffer on the GPU
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);     // "bind" or set as the current buffer we are working with
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);  // copy the data from CPU to GPU

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);             // Tell OpenGL to create new Vertex Array Object
    glBindVertexArray(vao);                 // Make it the current one
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);   // Define a layout for the first vertex buffer "0"
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);           // Enable the first attribute or attribute "0"

    // Set up index buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);  // Create buffer space on the GPU for the index buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(0);                   // unbind to make sure other code doesn't change it

    ShaderProgram shaderProgram;
    shaderProgram.loadShaders("shaders/basic.vert", "shaders/basic.frag");

    // Rendering loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(gWindow))
    {
        showFPS(gWindow);

        // Poll for and process events
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Clear the screen
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Render the quad
        // Must be called BEFORE setting uniforms because setting uniforms is done
        // on the currently active shader program.
        shaderProgram.use();

        GLfloat time = (GLfloat)glfwGetTime();
        GLfloat blueColor = (sin(time) / 2) + 0.5f;
        glm::vec2 pos;
        pos.x = sin(time) / 2;
        pos.y = cos(time) / 2;
        shaderProgram.setUniform("vertColor", glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, blueColor, 1.0f));
        shaderProgram.setUniform("posOffset", pos);

        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        // Swap front and back buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(gWindow);
    }

    // Clean up
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ibo);

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Initialize GLFW and OpenGL
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool initOpenGL()
{
    // Intialize GLFW
    // GLFW is configured.  Must be called before calling any GLFW functions
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        // An error occured
        std::cerr << "GLFW initialization failed" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);    // forward compatible with newer versions of OpenGL as they become available but not backward compatible (it will not run on devices that do not support OpenGL 3.3

    // Create an OpenGL 3.3 core, forward compatible context window
    gWindow = glfwCreateWindow(gWindowWidth, gWindowHeight, APP_TITLE, NULL, NULL);
    if (gWindow == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return false;
    }

    // Make the window's context the current one
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(gWindow);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Set the required callback functions
    glfwSetKeyCallback(gWindow, glfw_onKey);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(gWindow, glfw_onFramebufferSize);

    glClearColor(0.23f, 0.38f, 0.47f, 1.0f);

    // Define the viewport dimensions
    glViewport(0, 0, gWindowWidth, gWindowHeight);

    return true;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Is called whenever a key is pressed/released via GLFW
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void glfw_onKey(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);

    if (key == GLFW_KEY_W && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        gWireframe = !gWireframe;
        if (gWireframe)
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
        else
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Is called when the window is resized
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void glfw_onFramebufferSize(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Code computes the average frames per second, and also the average time it takes
// to render one frame.  These stats are appended to the window caption bar.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void showFPS(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    static double previousSeconds = 0.0;
    static int frameCount = 0;
    double elapsedSeconds;
    double currentSeconds = glfwGetTime(); // returns number of seconds since GLFW started, as double float

    elapsedSeconds = currentSeconds - previousSeconds;

    // Limit text updates to 4 times per second
    if (elapsedSeconds > 0.25)
    {
        previousSeconds = currentSeconds;
        double fps = (double)frameCount / elapsedSeconds;
        double msPerFrame = 1000.0 / fps;

        // The C++ way of setting the window title
        std::ostringstream outs;
        outs.precision(3);  // decimal places
        outs << std::fixed
            << APP_TITLE << "    "
            << "FPS: " << fps << "    "
            << "Frame Time: " << msPerFrame << " (ms)";
        glfwSetWindowTitle(window, outs.str().c_str());

        // Reset for next average.
        frameCount = 0;
    }

    frameCount++;
}
```

**ShaderProgram.h**

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "glm/glm.hpp"
using std::string;


class ShaderProgram
{
public:
     ShaderProgram();
    ~ShaderProgram();

    enum ShaderType
    {
        VERTEX,
        FRAGMENT,
        PROGRAM
    };

    // Only supports vertex and fragment (this series will only have those two)
    bool loadShaders(const char* vsFilename, const char* fsFilename);
    void use();

    GLuint getProgram() const;

    void setUniform(const GLchar* name, const glm::vec2& v);
    void setUniform(const GLchar* name, const glm::vec3& v);
    void setUniform(const GLchar* name, const glm::vec4& v);

private:

    string fileToString(const string& filename);
    void  checkCompileErrors(GLuint shader, ShaderType type);
    // We are going to speed up looking for uniforms by keeping their locations in a map
    GLint getUniformLocation(const GLchar * name);


    GLuint mHandle;
    std::map<string, GLint> mUniformLocations;
};
#endif // SHADER_H
```

**ShaderProgram.cpp**

```
#include "ShaderProgram.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Constructor
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram()
    : mHandle(0)
{}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Destructor
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ShaderProgram::~ShaderProgram()
{
    // Delete the program
    glDeleteProgram(mHandle);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Loads vertex and fragment shaders
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool ShaderProgram::loadShaders(const char* vsFilename, const char* fsFilename)
{
    string vsString = fileToString(vsFilename);
    string fsString = fileToString(fsFilename);
    const GLchar* vsSourcePtr = vsString.c_str();
    const GLchar* fsSourcePtr = fsString.c_str();

    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vsSourcePtr, NULL);
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fsSourcePtr, NULL);

    glCompileShader(vs);
    checkCompileErrors(vs, VERTEX);

    glCompileShader(fs);
    checkCompileErrors(fs, FRAGMENT);

    mHandle = glCreateProgram();
    if (mHandle == 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unable to create shader program!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    glAttachShader(mHandle, vs);
    glAttachShader(mHandle, fs);

    glLinkProgram(mHandle);
    checkCompileErrors(mHandle, PROGRAM);


    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    mUniformLocations.clear();

    return true;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Opens and reads contents of ASCII file to a string.  Returns the string.
// Not good for very large files.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
string ShaderProgram::fileToString(const string& filename)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::ifstream file;

    try
    {
        file.open(filename, std::ios::in);

        if (!file.fail())
        {
            // Using a std::stringstream is easier than looping through each line of the file
            ss << file.rdbuf();
        }

        file.close();
    }
    catch (std::exception ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error reading shader filename!" << std::endl;
    }

    return ss.str();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Activate the shader program
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void ShaderProgram::use()
{
    if (mHandle > 0)
        glUseProgram(mHandle);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Checks for shader compiler errors
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void  ShaderProgram::checkCompileErrors(GLuint shader, ShaderType type)
{
    int status = 0;

    if (type == PROGRAM)
    {
        glGetProgramiv(mHandle, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
        if (status == GL_FALSE)
        {
            GLint length = 0;
            glGetProgramiv(mHandle, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);

            // The length includes the NULL character
            string errorLog(length, ' ');   // Resize and fill with space character
            glGetProgramInfoLog(mHandle, length, &length, &errorLog[0]);
            std::cerr << "Error! Shader program failed to link. " << errorLog << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
        if (status == GL_FALSE)
        {
            GLint length = 0;
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);

            // The length includes the NULL character
            string errorLog(length, ' ');  // Resize and fill with space character
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, length, &length, &errorLog[0]);
            std::cerr << "Error! Shader failed to compile. " << errorLog << std::endl;
        }
    }

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Returns the active shader program
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
GLuint ShaderProgram::getProgram() const
{
    return mHandle;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sets a glm::vec2 shader uniform
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void ShaderProgram::setUniform(const GLchar* name, const glm::vec2& v)
{
    GLint loc = getUniformLocation(name);
    glUniform2f(loc, v.x, v.y);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sets a glm::vec3 shader uniform
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void ShaderProgram::setUniform(const GLchar* name, const glm::vec3& v)
{
    GLint loc = getUniformLocation(name);
    glUniform3f(loc, v.x, v.y, v.z);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sets a glm::vec4 shader uniform
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void ShaderProgram::setUniform(const GLchar* name, const glm::vec4& v)
{
    GLint loc = getUniformLocation(name);
    glUniform4f(loc, v.x, v.y, v.z, v.w);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Returns the uniform identifier given it's string name.
// NOTE: Shader must be currently active first.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
GLint ShaderProgram::getUniformLocation(const GLchar* name)
{
    std::map<string, GLint>::iterator it = mUniformLocations.find(name);

    // Only need to query the shader program IF it doesn't already exist.
    if (it == mUniformLocations.end())
    {
        // Find it and add it to the map
        mUniformLocations[name] = glGetUniformLocation(mHandle, name);
    }

    // Return it
    return mUniformLocations[name];
}
```

**basic.frag**

```
#version 330 core

uniform vec4 vertColor;
out vec4 frag_color;

void main()
{
    frag_color = vertColor;
}
```

**basic.vert**

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;

uniform vec2 posOffset;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(pos.x + posOffset.x, pos.y + posOffset.y, pos.z, 1.0);
}
```

---

*Также заметил что у вас есть спрос на качественные уроки по opengl. Лично мне понравились уроки от [Gameinstitute - OpenGL Graphics Programming](http://iv-torrents.ru/topic-game-institute-gameinstitute-opengl-graphics-programming-2016-eng-t=83890.html), у них как раз есть как видео так и файлы, а также интуитивно-понятное изложение.*

Comment: спасибо))) на счет видеоуроков, надеюсь будет раздача!)